# Can't tell if a Cake\ORM\Query was executed

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a custom model method executing a query, and I need it to return either true or false depending on whether it was successful. There's no clear answer, so I'm trying to figure out how it works myself. Here's my code:

```
// build and execute the query
$query = $myTable->query();
$query->insert(array_keys(reset($data)));
$query->clause('values')->setValues($data);
$query->epilog('ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `price`=VALUES(`price`)');
$statement = $query->execute();
```

Debugging the above looks like this:

```
'$statement' => object(Cake\Database\Statement\MysqlStatement) {
    [protected] _statement => object(PDOStatement) {
        queryString => 'INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `value_id`, `price`) VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `price`=VALUES(`price`)'
    }
    [protected] _driver => object(Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql) {

        'connected' => true

    }
    [protected] _hasExecuted => false
    [protected] _bufferResults => true
},
'$query' => object(Cake\ORM\Query) {

    '(help)' => 'This is a Query object, to get the results execute or iterate it.',
    'sql' => 'INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `value_id`, `price`) VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `price`=VALUES(`price`)',
    'params' => [
        // ...
    ],
    'defaultTypes' => [
        // ...
    ],
    'decorators' => (int) 0,
    'executed' => true,
    'hydrate' => true,
    'buffered' => true,
    'formatters' => (int) 0,
    'mapReducers' => (int) 0,
    'contain' => [],
    'matching' => [],
    'extraOptions' => [],
    'repository' => object(App\Model\Table\SomeTable) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Initial attempts:

- getting `$statement->errorCode` is null, not a 0
- getting `$statement->_hasExecuted` is null
- getting `$query->executed` throws *Notice Error: Undefined property: Cake\ORM\Query::$executed* (although it seems like it's there)
- what's interesting, in the debug output above, `$statement->_hasExecuted` is `false` and `$query->executed` is `true`

My thought process is this: I call [`$query->execute()`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/source-class-Cake.Database.Query.html#197-224), which inside of it [calls `$this->_connection->run($this)`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/source-class-Cake.Database.Query.html#219), which [creates and executes a `\Cake\Database\StatementInterface`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.Database.Connection.html#261-275). In my case it's a [`MysqlStatement` extended from a `PDOStatement`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Database/Statement/MysqlStatement.php). Inside the [`execute()` call](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/source-class-Cake.Database.Statement.StatementDecorator.html#161-175), it explicitly [sets `_hasExecuted` to true](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/source-class-Cake.Database.Statement.StatementDecorator.html#172); then it calls `$this->_statement->execute()`, which, [being an implementation of that same `Cake\Database\StatementInterface::execute()`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.Database.Statement.PDOStatement.html#_execute), apparently runs that exact execute method, including the `_hasExecuted`=`true` portion.

As far as I understand, that is the statement that is finally returned and shown in the debug above. And it has `_hasExecuted` set to `false`. So was it not executed?

This confuses me and I need your help. How do I tell for sure that the query was executed successfully? I can't look for lines affected count, because it may be 0. I asked on CakePHP Support Slack and was advised to check the debug panel or re-query the table later to confirm the entries were created, but I need this for an automated code test, so none of those would work.

Comment: @admad also suggested *if query wasn't successful due to sql error then you would get an exception. No exception means query was executed succesfully* -  does that mean I should wrap `$query->execute()` with a try-catch block and that's it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MySqlStatement::excute()` method doesn't change the `_hasExecuted` flag, and it also doesn't call the parent method. This could be an oversight, it could also be by design, not changing the flag for example allows to iterate the statement more than once (which involves issuing the query again), you could open an issue over at GitHub for clarification, or try to summon the ORM Guru aka Lorenzo via Slack.

The `Query::$executed` property really doesn't exist, what you're looking at there is [**custom debug information**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.8.1/src/Database/Query.php#L2327) that doesn't reflect the object structure, the `executed` key is based on the internal `_iterator` property.

If executing the query doesn't trigger an exception, then it has run successfully, ie without errors on the DBMS side, unless of course you've changed the connection's error mode to *silent* or *warning* mode, that's when you could/would use `errorCode()`, which otherwise won't be available as the exception would prevent the statement to be available in the first place.

Whether no DBMS error means that your query did exactly what it was intended to do, might be a different question, and depends on what exactly the query does, and is something that you need to figure out on a case by case basis. Your only options for actual verification are looking at the number of affected rows, and/or querying the database afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

What about `query()->execute()->execute()`? It at least returns a boolean.